Unable run ubuntu with my tv connect with HDMI
I have a pc with two displays. One is a standard pc monitor and the other is a tv. I usually use only the pc monitor but sometimes i need to extende it with the tv. In windows everything works fine.
I have ubuntu 24.04 and the last nvidia drivers. Even if the tv is turned off if i boot ubuntu i have a black screen. I do not know what is happening but if I unplug the hdmi then everything works fine and the loggin screen appears. I do not know how to set up the second monitor because if I plug again the hdmi then again the display becomes completely black.
Anyone can help?
